# jQuery previous month jumps to random month instead of previous month

Tags: jquery

I have one application with 2 different tabs where `calendar/date-picker` is used. If I switch from one tab to another by using calendar functionality then I see one issue. The issue is, when I try to click on previous month icon then it jumps to any random month instead of previous month.
e.g. Current month is May 2021 (07/05/2021) and if I click on previous month then it will jump to October 2020.

I did some analysis and found that there is bug in `jQuery UI` library. Following are the links for the same.

```
https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/15129 ,
https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/7288 ,
https://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/9923#comment:4
```

I tried using different versions of `jQuery UI` libraries. But I can see the same issue with all the libraries. Following are the libraries that I used.

```
jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js
jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js
jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js
jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom.min.js
jquery-ui-1.12.1.custom.min.js
```

Is that bug fixed in any recent version. If it is already fixed then can you please help me what exactly I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

You did test all stable versions.

1.12.1 was the latest version, released in 2016.
Support for this API is [not really active](https://blog.jqueryui.com/2017/12/the-future-of-jquery-ui-and-jquery-mobile/), but some fix are still pushed on their [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui).

You may unfortunately have to debug it yourself if you need it fixed.

Comment: Thank you JardonS for the quick response. After analysis/debugging I found the root cause.  I was using same id in the input tag for both the calendar's at different locations and it was causing the issue after switching the tabs.

Answer (score 1):

After analysis, found that the same id was used in both the tabs. The reason was both the calendars were using same id for the input tag. If I select date in tab A by choosing previous/next month and then switching to tab B then it was picking the month where I left the month in tab A.
E.g. Current month is May 2021. If I select date from Previous month like Sept 2020 in tab A and then if I move to tab B, the default month will be May 2021 and if I click on previous month then it will jump to Aug 2020 because I left the month Sept 2020 in other tab.